# Android custom preference value not saved

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an existing Preference subclass to work that saves a color value. I didn't write the class, but it's supposed to be working on android-7 and above (I'm compiling to an android-9 target.) The full source code is [available here](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference/blob/master/src/com/att/preference/colorpicker/ColorPickerPreference.java). Here's where the preference is saved:

```
@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    if (isPersistent()) {
        boolean ret = persistInt(color);
    }
    // (update preview box, other stuff)
}
```

Using debug output I can tell that `isPersistent()` returns `true`, but `persistInt()` returns `false`. According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#persistInt%28int%29), `persistInt()` returns whether the preference is persistent; how can these return different values? (Note: `setPersistent(true)` is explicitly called from the constructor.)

In any case, the value is not saved. A call to `getPersistedInt(defaultValue)` returns the default value, even later in the same instance of the class. In the code below, `getPersistedInt()` is always called and always returns `mDefaultValue`.

```
public int getValue() {
    try {
        if (isPersistent()) {
            mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefaultValue);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        mValue = mDefaultValue;
    }

    return mValue;
}
```

Why is this, and how can I make sure the preference is persisted?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had looked at yours but decided against it, because while RGB sliders can be useful for non-touchscreen phones, my app requires a touchscreen anyway, and I'd prefer some kind of HSL picker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After lots of hopeless searching, I finally found the problem: the preference value was not assigned a key, due to a simple typo in my preferences XML file. (I used `android.key` instead of `android:key`.)

Since Android doesn't warn you when trying to persist a preference that has no key (but silently fails instead,) you should call the `shouldPersist()` function instead of `isPersistent()` before trying to persist a value, and perhaps log a warning if `shouldPersist()` returns false. For example:

```
@Override
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    mValue = color;
    if (shouldPersist()) {
        persistInt(color);
    } else {
        if (isPersistent())
            Log.w("myapp", "shouldPersist() returned false. Check if this preference has a key.");
    }
    // (update preview box, other stuff)
}
```